# Script and Content editor web parts missing from SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, content-editor-web-part, script-editor-webpart

I am working with SP 2019 on prem. Noticing one of the most weird issues. 
I have SharePoint server publishing and SharePoint Server publishing infrastructure enabled. Seeing below when editing a classic page, no content/script editor web parts available

[image]

See below configuration for web app level,
[image]

I also disabled SP Server publishing feature and reactivated it, still no luck.
Under same web application, if I create a brand new site collection, I see all classic web parts, script/content editor everything, no issues. So I think its site collection specific issue.

if any one experienced this before, please shed some light, appreciate the help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually figured out what's wrong. Upon viewing the page source code, the variable g_wsaSiteTemplate had value assigned as: 'SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0  which means site collection was created using the Communication Site (publishing) and there is no way it will support script or content editor web parts there and many other web parts like page viewer, content search.

Answer (score 1):

What’s the permission of the user who want to add the web parts?

Go to site settings->site permissions->check permissions, check what’s the permission level that the user assigned. And check if the “Add and Customize Pages” permission is ticked.

Comment: I am the site collection admin and site owner as well, see screenshot added in question description please

Answer (score 0):

It is directly possible only through powershell using the command (limited to Tenant admins):
Set-SPOsite https://your-domain.sharepoint.com/sites/modern-site -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

An alternative approach has been described here: [PNP Modern Script editor](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2023/03/15/use-script-editor-modern-sharepoint-sites/)